# Ubuntu Desktop 16 to duplicate/clone a running terminal console

Tags: console, clone, duplicate

Sometimes I want to clone/duplicate a running terminal console so that I can work on the current thread/process without having to re-run all executed commands from the beginning. E.g. running a Flask web application with some system variable to export first.

So, is it possible to clone a terminal to get an exact cloned console?